# PyQt: Controlling position of QGraphicsRectItem with setRect()

Tags: python, pyqt

I am taking my first shot at PyQT, in order to eventually create quite basic graphic representation of some data.
I am currently trying to box two `QGraphicsTextItem`s inside `QGraphicsRectItem`, and I have some question regarding some result I see.

```
class MyRect(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyRect, self).__init__(parent)

        self.text_item  = QGraphicsTextItem('My Text Here', self)
        self.value_item = QGraphicsTextItem('My Value Here', self)
        self.text_item.setDefaultTextColor(QColor(Qt.blue))
        self.value_item.setDefaultTextColor(QColor(Qt.red))

        self.value_item.setPos(self.text_item.boundingRect().bottomLeft())

        width  = max(self.text_item.boundingRect().width(), self.value_item.boundingRect().width())
        height = self.text_item.boundingRect().height() + self.value_item.boundingRect().height()
        self.setRect(50, 50, width, height)


class MainFrame(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        ### setting up the scene
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)

        ### setting up MyRect
        my_rect = MyRect()

        self.scene.addItem(my_rect)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Basic test")
```

The above produce this:
[image]
which is not quite what I intended.
After some more experimenting, I found out that changing this:

```
self.setRect(50, 50, width, height)
```

to this:

```
self.setRect(0, 0, width, height)
self.setPos(50, 50)
```

made the trick:
[image]
How come?
What's the difference between setting position of the rectangle with `setRect()`, and setting position explicitly with `setPos()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the functions are defined with respect to different coordinate systems. According to the documentation, `setPos()` defines the position of the rectangle in ***its parent's coordinate*** system, while `setRect()` defines the position and size of the rectangle within ***its own local coordinate system***. So The `(x,y)` of `setPos()` and the `(x,y)` of `setRect()` do not have the same meaning.

With `setPos(50, 50)`, you're saying the origin of the rectangle's local coordinate system is located at position `(50, 50)` in the coordinate system of the `QGraphicsScene` (its parent). Then with `setRect(0, 0, width, height)`, you're saying the rectangle is located at the origin `(0,0)` in its own coordinate system (which is actually `(50, 50)` in the scene coordinate system).

Comment: It's an oldish question, but maybe it'll help someone. I'm just learning PyQt myself, and ran into this same issue very recently.